# how to delete a file recursively from folders on mac / unix

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I want to delete ._DS_Store file from the parent folder and all sub folders. How to delete the .DS_Store file recursively from all folders with single command?
(using rm -rf command)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
find parent_dir -name .DS_Store -delete
```

With GNU find at least.  Otherwise

```
find parent_dir -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Or

```
find parent_dir -name .DS_Store -exec rm -f +
```

Comment: BSD (Mac OS X) `find` supports `-delete` too.

Comment: "find parent_dir -name .DS_Store -delete" and "find . -name ".DS_Store" -type f -delete " worked for me. thank you.

Comment: Here double quote was necessary on "+" or ";".
```find $(pwd) -name "*.dSYM" -exec rm -r {} "+"```

Comment: @diogo-b013 the semicolon would need to be escaped if one were to use that, but in bash at least the + does not need to be escaped or quoted

Answer (score 1):

To do this in the current directory you can do

```
find $(pwd) -name .DS_Store -delete
```

or other commands in place of `-delete` as show in previous answer.